# Call to a member function toJson() on a non-object Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

From below code reference, I am joining the users table, `user_details` table and `user_config` table with each record similar key and no problem with that (it works), yet when I'm trying to convert the result records to json array, it gives me this error

> Call to a member function toJson() on a non-object

```
public function get_users_table(){
       $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_details.id')
        ->join('user_config', 'users.id', '=', 'user_config.id')
        //->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
        ->get()->toJson();

       return response()->json(['success' => true, 'users' => $users]);
    }
```

Any ideas, help?

Comment: you dont need `->toJson()` because your response type is `json` and it will handle it.

Comment: thank you! thats was quick and simple.

Comment: Normally you should have simply **replaced** `->get()` with `->toJson()` to get a JSON encoded string, but in your case as @K.Toress pointed out, that's redundant because the response will handle the conversion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

get() returns an array not an object. You can simply do json_encode($users);